# Help improving a diagram with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to get the hang of Tikz - I've seen some amazing stuff done with it out there. I'm currently writing a Pure Maths book for A-Level and I need to include loads of diagrams, one of which is:
[image]

I love how clean it looks. I tried to replicate it with Tikz:

[image]

It's just not as neat and easy on the eye. Can anyone give me some suggestions on how I can improve my diagrams? Here's a MWE of the above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
        \draw (0,-0.3) node[left]{$O$};
        \draw (-1,0.5)--(8,5);
        \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (8,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
        \draw (2,2) node{\textbullet};
        \draw (2.6,2) node[below] {$B$\tiny$(x_2,y_2)$};
        \draw (6,4) node{\textbullet};
        \draw (6.8,4) node[below] {$A$\tiny$(x_1,y_1)$};
        \draw[<->, dashed] (6,4)--(6,2) node[right]{$P$};
        \draw[<->, dashed] (2,2)--(6,2);
        \draw[<->, dashed] (1.8,2.5)--(5.8,4.5);
        \draw[dotted](6,2)--(6,0);
        \draw[dotted](2,2)--(2,0);
        \draw(3.7, 3.8) node{$s$};
        \draw(4.3, 1.7) node{$x_1-x_2$};
        \draw(6.8, 3) node{$y_1-x_2$};
        \draw[<->,dashed](1.5,0)--(1.5,2);
        \draw(1.8, 1) node{$y_2$};
        \draw[<->,dashed](1,0)--(1,4);
        \draw(0.8, 2) node{$y_1$};
        \draw[<->,dashed](0,-0.5)--(2,-0.5);
        \draw(1, -0.3) node{$x_2$};
        \draw[<->,dashed](0,-0.8)--(6,-0.8);
        \draw(3, -1) node{$x_1$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Nice effort, it can probably be improved quite a bit but just off the top of my head I would recommend moving the $y_1$ and $y_2$ “gauges” back to the left of the $y$ axis.  It looks a little cluttered the way you’ve done it right now.

Comment: Assuming you want B&W for printing purposes, you can also use grey and vary the thickness.

Answer (score 11):

Here are some changes you could try. There are many more that could be done, but it's no use to try everything at once. One thing that simplifies things a lot is placing a node directly along a path, using keywords such as `midway`, `above`, etc. It avoids having to manually compute coordinates to place things. I also set the font size for all nodes at the very beginning of the picture, with `every node/.style`. Notice also how the arrow points at $A$ and $B$ don't overlap the dots. This is because when you draw a path towards a node, the path stops just clear of the node. That is why I gave names for the nodes for those points. A name is given to a node by placing the name within parentheses :

```
node[<options>] (<name>) ...other stuff...
```

Then when I want to draw a path to a node, I simply used the nodes's name and not the explicit coordinates. Read the code you will notice many other things.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={node font=\scriptsize}]
\draw (0,-0.3) node[left]{$O$};
\draw (-1,0.5)--(8,5);
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (8,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
\node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=below right:{$B(x_2,y_2)$}] (B) at (2,2) {};
\node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=below right:{$A(x_1,y_1)$}] (A) at (6,4) {};
\draw[<->, dashed] (A)--(6,2) node[right]{$P$} node[midway,right] {$y_2-y_1$};
\draw[<->, dashed] (B)--(6,2) node[midway,below] {$x_1-x_2$};
\draw[<->, dashed] ($(A)+(0,0.5)$) -- ($(B) + (0,0.5)$) node[above,midway] {$s$};
\draw[dotted](6,2)--(6,0);
\draw[dotted](2,2)--(2,0);
\draw[<->,dashed](-0.5,0)-- ++(0,2) node[midway,right] {$y_2$};
\draw[<->,dashed](-0.75,0)-- ++(0,4) node[midway,left]{$y_1$};
\draw[<->,dashed](0,-0.5)--(2,-0.5);
\draw(1, -0.3) node{$x_2$};
\draw[<->,dashed](0,-0.8)--(6,-0.8);
\draw(3, -1) node{$x_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The final result is
[image]